# How to possibly extend a generic delegate type with a non-generic one in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, syntax, delegates

I would like to define a non-generic delegate extending a generic delegate to define a default for the generic delegate type parameter, i.e. something like this (not a valid piece of C# code but an obvious-to-understand illustration for the concept I mean hopefully):

```
public delegate void MyDelegate<T>(T arg);

public delegate void MyDelegate(object arg) : MyDelegate<object>;
```

What is, if any, the correct way to declare this?

Needless to say I can just declare 2 independent delegates to achieve virtually same effect a way like this:

```
public delegate void MyDelegate<T>(T arg);

public delegate void MyDelegate(object arg);
```

but I'd like to do to make the actual relation between them (the fact a bare `MyDelegate` type is meant to equal `MyDelegate<object>`, the way like a class extending another class or literally) definite and make the following code will become valid if possible:

```
MyDelegate<object> d1;

MyDelegate d2;

MyDelegate d1 = d2;
```

Comment: Delegate types are sealed, as you should well know. They can't be inherited. What are you [really trying to do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What would you gain by expressing your delegate declarations in this way? Note that delegates are, in a sense, single-member interfaces. So if you _really_ need to do this, it's likely expressing your relationship as an `interface` type instead of as a `delegate` type would be more appropriate.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I feel a way embarrassed but I didn't know they're sealed and an idea to check whether or not they are  hasn't came into my mind :-] Thank you for telling. You can submit this as an answer and I'll accept it if so. I have extended the question with an example of what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I may have been too harsh in saying you should know delegate types are sealed. It is clear in the specification, but I took a look at the latest version of the MSDN language documentation, and it does not seem to mention this at all. Well, anyway…they are sealed.  You can't create a new class that inherits a delegate type, and you certainly can't use the `delegate` keyword to declare a new delegate type that inherits another delegate type (the keyword has a very specific syntax, and doesn't even allow an inheritance syntax).

It's still not really clear to me what you're trying to do. But, in some sense, a delegate type is an interface with just one member. It's more flexible, of course, because the implementation isn't in a single type, but can be any method from any type. But conceptually, the two are very similar.

In that sense, you could express your intent in code using an `interface` instead of a `delegate`. For example:

```
interface IDelegate<T>
{
    void M(T arg);
}

interface IDelegateObject : IDelegate<object> { }
```

Of course, the problem with this is that now you need some type that will implement the interface in question. Any given type will only be able to implement any given interface once, so you lose a lot of the flexibility that delegate types would ordinarily give you.

But, you *can* do something like this:

```
IDelegate<object> d1;
IDelegateObject d2;

d1 = d2;
```

That is, since `IDelegateObject` inherits `IDelegate<object>`, and thus "is a" `IDelegate<object>`, you can then assign a value of type `IDelegateObject`, i.e. `d2`, to a variable of type `IDelegate<object>`, i.e. `d1`.

Comment: And with interfaces you can use variance - so even some more assignments can be done if you use `IDelegate<out T>` or `IDelegate<in T>` depending on your needs/options.